# Multiple fields in web2py FORM

Tags: forms, position, field, web2py

I want to make a simple FORM (not SQLFORM) in web2py with two fields namely 'name' and 'password'.
I have used the following code

```
form=FORM('Cloned VM Name:',INPUT(_name='name',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
          'VNC Password:',INPUT(_name='password',_type='password',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
           INPUT(_type='submit', _value='Clone it!'))
```

I could generate the form but the fields are not appearing what we expect
it like
[image]

Is there a way i can position the fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FORM and INPUT helpers are just replacements for the HTML `<form>` and `<input>` tags, so your code will produce this HTML:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Cloned VM Name:<input name="name" type="text" />
VNC Password:<input name="password" type="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Clone it!" />
</form>
```

Depending on how you want the form formatted, you could add additional web2py HTML helpers and/or use CSS. For example, if you want each input on a separate line, just put each one into a DIV:

```
form=FORM(DIV('Cloned VM Name:',INPUT(_name='name',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY())),
     DIV('VNC Password:',
         INPUT(_name='password',_type='password',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY())),
     DIV(INPUT(_type='submit',_value='Clone it!')))
```

Alternatively, if you want to take advantage of some of web2py's SQLFORM functionality (such as the `formstyle` argument to control the formatting) but do not want to base the form on a database table, you can use [SQLFORM.factory](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#SQLFORM.factory).

Comment: Thanks, you make me understood the complete concept.